# Why interior point of feasible region of linear programming problem can't be optimal solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Solution set will be null or singular or infinite. Optimal solution set if not null has at least one extreme point. I have feeling that optimal solution will be on boundary only but don't know how to show it mathematically that interior point can't be optimal solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_programming

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the linear programming problem

$$\min_{x \in F} c^Tx$$

where $F$ is a polyhedral.

If $c=0$, then every point, including any interior point is indeed an optimal solution.

However, if $c \neq 0$, by definition of an interior point, $y$, we can find a small neighborhood $N$ around $y$ such that $N \subset F$. we consider the point $y-\epsilon c$ where $\epsilon>0$ is chosen to be small enough such that $y-\epsilon c \in N$. hence $y-\epsilon c$ is feasible and we have $$c^T(y-\epsilon c^T)=c^Ty-\epsilon c^Tc=c^Ty-\epsilon\|c\|^2 < c^Ty,$$ hence the interior point $y$ is not optimal.

Comment: To the point. thanks:)